# Use ES Modules from content_scripts of Web Extension (add-on)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Since the latest Firefox supports ES Modules without flags as well as Chrome, I would like to use `import`/`export` for my web extension (add-on). Pop up, background and option pages were OK by simply using `<script type="module">`.

How do you make modules work in [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts)?

I tried and saw followings:

(1) Just write `import` in a acript declared at `content_scripts.js` in `manifest.json`

```
import Foo from './foo.js';
```

> (Chrome) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Firefox doesn't work with no errors.

(2) Run through `tabs.executeScript()`

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(undefined, {
  file: "foo.js",
});
```

> (Chrome) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> (Firefox) Error: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

(3) Insert a script element created with `type="module"`

```
const el = document.createElement("script");
el.src = browser.extension.getURL("foo.js");
el.type = "module";
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

> (Chrome) Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: browser is not defined
>
> (Firefox) ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: AFAIK modules aren't supported in content scripts. Probably because those are not like the extension pages with their own URL, but just a bunch of scripts "sideloaded" along web pages.

Answer (score 3):

**One easy solution is using some bundler to bundle your content script.**
It may sound complicated, but with bundler like **[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)** you can do this very easily with super simple "rollup.config.js" file:

```
export default {
  input: 'content_script.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle_content_script.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
};
```

Rollup will only replace your imports with actual code, so there is no boilerplate and the code is still readable.

**You may also want to read:**

1. bundlers comparison: https://medium.com/@ajmeyghani/javascript-bundlers-a-comparison-e63f01f2a364
2. bundling multiple scripts: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/703

Using bundler will also speed-up loading time, for me it went down from 335ms to 63ms (but I have 100+ modules now).